# Scala - recursive function not returning the object

Tags: scala, recursion

I have the following object structure:

```
case class Node(id:Int,children:List[Node])
```

Example:

```
NodeA
    id: 1
    children:[
        NodeA1:
            id: 2
            children:
                NodeA11
                ...
        ]       
        NodeB1:
            id: 3
            children:[]
        NodeC1:
            id: 17
            children: [
                NodeC11:
                    id:11
                    children:[
                        NodeC111:
                            id: 19
                            children: []
                    ]

            ]
        ...
```

I would like to create a recursive looping to get the Node that has a specific Id but i'm stuck in how to keep running the fuction if the iD isn't found and the object has any object on children list. My function only works to get the first node (ex.: Id = 1).

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
def getNode(id:Int, node:Node) : Node = {
    var result:Node = null
    if(node.id == id){
      return node
    } else if(node.children.size > 0 ){
      for(children <- node.children){
        result = getNode(id, children)
        if(result.id == id){
          return result
        }
      }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to return `null` when nothing is found?

Comment: it could be null, none or an exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function `getNode` really should return `Option[Node]` to account for searches for an `id` missing in the `Node` tree.

And in that case you can compose Options of recursive calls:

```
def getNode(id:Int, node:Node): Option[Node] = 
  if (node.id == id) Some(node)
  else node.children.collectFirst(Function.unlift(getNode(id, _)))
```

In imperative case you don't need the check for list length: just return `None`/`null` after the loop where you check every child (or don't check if there aren't any children).

```
def getNode(id:Int, node:Node) : Option[Node] = {
  if (node.id == id) Some(node)
  else {
    for (child <- node.children) {
      val result = getNode(id, child)
      // At this point `result` is Some(nodeWeAreLookingFor) 
      // if it is in the subtree of the current `child`
      // or None otherwise
      if (result.isDefined) return result
    }
    None
  }
}
```

For Java you can of course replace `Option` with `null`, but in Scala this idea is naturally modelled by `Option`

Comment: So elegant...i was just wondering, how to code the else condition on imperative way? i'm asking because i'm java developer and i would to make a parallel on those languages

Comment: @placplacboom I've added a part for the imperative case

Comment: inside the for loop, just use `return getNode(id, child)`, no need to verify the Option is define or not.

Comment: Just played with Function.unlift, it's awesome!